# Do good deeds (Hassanat) go in vain if we help the Non-Muslims?

Tags: sharia, reward

Will our good deeds (Hassanat) go in vain if we help people practicing some other or no religion?

I know a good deed is rewarded after multiplication of itself by ten. Is this still valid if we help (non-believers)?

Comment: What do you mean by kuffar? Can you give an example

Comment: As i stated, those of different religion to Islam or with no religion those who do not believe in Allah (SWT), basically i live in a country which is not Islamic and i meet a lot of people from different cultures!

Comment: You don't know somebody's religion and helping him is also a good deed so you would get what you did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your definition of kuffar is inaccurate. You can search this site or ask question to know the difference between a kafir and non-muslim.

There are numerous verses in Quran that tells us to do good deeds towards every human being as well as other creatures. This opinion is also strengthened by the actions of our prophet (PBUH), who is the best example for us in the matters of religion.

So you will get the reward of every single good deed that you do towards anyone.